# Why can't be a JS object literal converted to JSON ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, frontend, ecma

Since tutorials claim that with Javascript objects can be converted into JSON but 
when I try to convert this:

```
var myObj = { name:"John", age:31, city:"New York" };
```

using this:

```
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(myObj);
window.location = "demo_json.php?x=" + myJSON;
```

it doesn't work.

but if I do this:

```
var myObj = { "name":"John", "age":31, "city":"New York" };
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(myObj);
window.location = "demo_json.php?x=" + myJSON;
```

it works.

Why ? If it claims to convert JS object to JSON then why it doesn't ? Why do I have to put quotes around the strings ? If I put quotes then it isn't an JS object anymore.

Comment: What does _"it doesn't work"_ mean?

Comment: Its realy dump to send json string with httpget,  without encoding it first

Comment: Quotes or not doesn't change whether or not it's a JS object.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
var myObj = { name:"John", age:31, city:"New York" };
var encodedParams = $.param(myObj);

console.log(encodedParams);
```

I hope it helped you !

Answer (score 2):

Look at this [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zk7k2snm/). It converts it just fine. The stringify creates a string representation of the JSON object. Are you getting a JavaScript error in the console output of the browser?

```js
var myObj = { name:"John", age:31, city:"New York" };
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(myObj);
var test = "demo_json.php?x=" + myJSON;

document.querySelector("#test").innerText = test;
```

```html
<div id='test'></div>
```

Comment: @Hassan Imam Any reason you edited my post and added jQuery? The code doesn't need jQuery to run. It's using the Selector API for JavaScript. Just curious.

Comment: Apology man, yeah you can remove Jquery. I thought you were using Jquery, that's why I included it. The above code doesn't need Jquery.

Comment: No problem. I just thought I missed something. Wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

It's working here.

```js
var myObj = { name:"John", age:31, city:"New York" };
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(myObj);

console.log(myJSON);
alert(myJSON);
```